# Transfer the special character (e.g. Chinese chararcter) form PHP to android

Tags: php, android

This is how I send the text message to android GCM , first I encode the chinese character in PHP

```
$message = array("msg" => urlencode($msg));

$url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
$fields = array(
            'registration_ids'  => $registrationIDs,
            'data'              => array( "message" => $message ),
            );

$headers = array(
                'Authorization: key=' . $api_key,
                'Content-Type: application/json;');

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

when the message send to android side , the symobal , digit number and english are remain normal , however, the chinese character is not, how to fix it ?  thanks

```
msg = URLDecoder.decode(intent.getStringExtra("message"), "UTF-8");
```

Comment: both side use UTF-8 encoding .

Comment: I have already saved my php as utf 8 without dom  , is it ok?

Comment: actually i don't knw about php i only knw android dude :)

Comment: by default java string itself is unicode if u use UTF-8 in server side communication then all special char with other language like Chinese,Japanese is also   support

Comment: In my case the return message will be {msg:null} if I input chinese in php side, while english and other symobol work normally

Comment: ohk then said to your android developer that when he/she take a response then covert that response into unicode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem is not caused by the php or android

actually in my input form omitted the

```
<meta type="utf-8">
```

That is careless mistake

Answer (score 1):

Try set set the php header charset to UTF-8 and see if it works.

Comment: tried $headers = array(
    'Authorization: key='.$api_key,
    'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8'); but it still not works

Answer (score 1):

Add to the html head:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```